# Problems when using multiple keys in a jks (ssl)

Tags: security, ssl, pkcs#12, jks

I have two client pkcs12 keystores. I exported the certs out of both of those and added them to a new jks using keyman. The strange thing is that each keystore seperately works fine, but when i combine them into one keystore, both calls to each client fail with

```
<pre><code>org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer#0-1, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 32
org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer#0-1, handling exception: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer#0-1, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, description = unexpected_message
org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer#0-1, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 18
org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer#0-1, Exception sending alert: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer#0-1, called closeSocket()
org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer#0-1, called close()
org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer#0-1, called closeInternal(true)
org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer#0-1, called close()
org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer#0-1, called closeInternal(true)
org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer#0-1, called close()
org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer#0-1, called closeInternal(true)
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:168)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:293)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:331)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:798)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1138)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:632)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:59)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:65)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:123)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.flushRequestOutputStream(HttpConnection.java:828)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$HttpConnectionAdapter.flushRequestOutputStream(MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java:1565)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.writeRequest(HttpMethodBase.java:2116)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:1096)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:398)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:323)
    at com.att.socialnetworkingmanager.util.HttpRequestUtil.post_aroundBody4(HttpRequestUtil.java:140)
    at com.att.socialnetworkingmanager.util.HttpRequestUtil.post_aroundBody5$advice(HttpRequestUtil.java:65)
    at com.att.socialnetworkingmanager.util.HttpRequestUtil.post(HttpRequestUtil.java:1)
    at com.att.socialnetworkingmanager.util.HttpRequestUtil.post_aroundBody2(HttpRequestUtil.java:89)
    at com.att.socialnetworkingmanager.util.HttpRequestUtil.post_aroundBody3$advice(HttpRequestUtil.java:65)
    at com.att.socialnetworkingmanager.util.HttpRequestUtil.post(HttpRequestUtil.java:1)
    at com.att.socialnetworkingmanager.sng.impl.SocialNetworkingAuthenticationImpl.getSngAccessToken_aroundBody0(SocialNetworkingAuthenticationImpl.java:87)
    at com.att.socialnetworkingmanager.sng.impl.SocialNetworkingAuthenticationImpl.getSngAccessToken_aroundBody1$advice(SocialNetworkingAuthenticationImpl.java:65)
    at com.att.socialnetworkingmanager.sng.impl.SocialNetworkingAuthenticationImpl.getSngAccessToken(SocialNetworkingAuthenticationImpl.java:1)
    at com.att.socialnetworkingmanager.service.impl.UploadManagerImpl.sendToSng_aroundBody0(UploadManagerImpl.java:61)
    at com.att.socialnetworkingmanager.service.impl.UploadManagerImpl.sendToSng_aroundBody1$advice(UploadManagerImpl.java:65)
    at com.att.socialnetworkingmanager.service.impl.UploadManagerImpl.sendToSng(UploadManagerImpl.java:1)
    at com.att.socialnetworkingmanager.jms.SocialNetworkingManagerQueueListener.onMessage_aroundBody0(SocialNetworkingManagerQueueListener.java:52)
    at com.att.socialnetworkingmanager.jms.SocialNetworkingManagerQueueListener.onMessage_aroundBody1$advice(SocialNetworkingManagerQueueListener.java:65)
    at com.att.socialnetworkingmanager.jms.SocialNetworkingManagerQueueListener.onMessage(SocialNetworkingManagerQueueListener.java:1)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.MessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(MessageListenerAdapter.java:343)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:518)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:479)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:451)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:323)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:261)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:982)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:974)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:876)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)</code></pre>
```

I'm not sure what is happening because i have done this before. Any ideas why this fails when combining certs from both clients?

Answer (score 1):

You said you exported the certificates out of both key stores - did you also export the associated keys?

TLS client authentication does need the keys, too. The certificates alone won't get you far.

Additionally, your idea could potentially cause problems when selecting the correct key/certificate for a given connection: you must be sure that you correctly select them, typically a client authentication key/certificate pair is supposed to work only for one dedicated service, so mixing up the keys would result in a rejected connection attempt.

Comment: Yes i exported the associated keys as well. I have the whole chain for both clients. If what you are saying is correct, what is the best approach to take when having an java ee application that will connect to two or more secure server?

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar problem when using multiple keys in the same keystore.jks file. We had the same behaviour, when we used each key separately, the access worked without any problem. When we put both keys into the same keystore, we got the error "403: Forbidden".

After creating new certificates and more, we found out that the name of the certificates in the keystore has an influence:

one of the keys had the name (anonymized):

> test-cert-of_company

and did not work. After changing to **cert_of_company** it worked.

> cert_of_company

We guess that the character "-" in the name did cause the problem and the replacement to "_" solved it. Maybe this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use `keytool` to list the contents of your combined key store.

What is the "type" of each entry?

They should be a private key entries; if not (if they are trusted entries), you failed to export the associated private keys.

Are the two certificates from the same issuer?